# Как исправить ошибку с исключеним org.xml.sax.SAXParseException для spring-mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb

После смены версии библиотеки spring-data-mongodb с 1.10.22 на 2.1.9 или 2.0.14 приложение при запуске бросает исключение:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongoContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 83; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:250)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 83; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1912)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 30 more
```

Вот код файла конфигурации mongoContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation=
           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<!-- MongoDB host -->
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${repository.host}" port="${repository.port}" />

<!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="discovery" />
</bean>

<!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
<mongo:repositories base-package="ru.leasoft.discovery.domain.core.services.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Используется java 1.8.

Версия gradle:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-54-generic amd64
```

Comment: вы бы лучше xml привели, т.к. ошибка в том, что файл не может распарситься

Comment: `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 83; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.`

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вы указали не все пространства имен (xmlns) или не все схемы. Вот [пример из доки](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: В этом конфиг-файле только эти используются. Если добавить любые другие - студия помечает их как неиспользуемые. Результат при этом тот же.

Comment: Все другие пространства имён указаны в других конфигах. Система работала до замены версии spring-data-mongodb  на последнюю.